# IndexError: index 6842 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6842

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, encoding

I know this probably is a pretty dumb error but I'm stuck with this. I need to 1-hot encode an array with numpy:

numpy.**version** ==> 1.18.5

```
print(array)
[[   3 1275   10 ...    1 2235    1]
 [   0    0    0 ...    2  139  151]
 [1277 1278    1 ... 2239  831    1]
 ...
 [   2 6833   28 ...   25  520    1]
 [   0    0    0 ...    4  481    1]
 [   0    0    0 ... 6842 6843    1]]


print(array.shape)
# (1250, 20)    

print(array_classes)
# 6842
```

And when I try to create the one-hot encode of the array:

```
ohe = np.eye(array_classes)[array]
```

I get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-3a05df861550> in <module>()
      1 print(array_classes)
      2 print(array)
----> 3 ohe = np.eye(array_classes)[array]

IndexError: index 6842 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 6842
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a much more simple example of my error and expected output:

Here is my initial array: (shape (2, 20), 2 examples, 20 values each)

```
array = array[:2]
print(array)
[[   3 1275   10 2231  830    1 2232    1 2233    4  220    1  339    1
  2234   15  477    1 2235    1]
 [   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1276    1    2
  2236 2237   30    2  139  151]]
```

Here are the num of total classes:

```
 print(array_classes)
 # 6842
```

I create the Identity matrix with the number of classes:

```
 matrix = np.eye(array_classes)
 print(matrix, matrix.shape)
[[1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]] (6843, 6843)
```

And then I multiply my initital array to my identity matrix and I get the 1-hot encoded version of my array:

```
ohe = matrix[array]
print(ohe, ohe.shape)

[[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  ...
  [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]] (2, 20, 6843)
```

Comment: Let's assume I have an array `myArray` that is 3 elements long. `["a", "b", "c"]`. To address the first element of the array I do `myArray[0]`. To address the last element I do `myArray[2]`. If I go beyond that it will be out of bound.

Comment: I know, but I think I do not understand the reason why I get this error in my code. The result of `ohe` should be an array of shape `(1250, 20, 6842)`

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what is the expected result? I don't understand how a 2D array of shape (1250, 20) should one-hot encode a (6842, 6842) array.

Comment: `import numpy as np; np.eye(5)` is a 2D array of 0s and 1s. You then address those values. The only result that can come out is 0 and 1.  

Can you rephrase your question with a smaller array example but still fully reproducible and then explain what value you expect?

Comment: `1250` is the number of sentences, `20` is the length of each sentence and `6842` is the lenth of the vocabulary. Using np.eye() I need to 1-hot encode a 2D array and it should output a 3D array with shape `(1250, 20, 6842)`, creating a 1-hot encoding in 3 dimensions

Comment: @TinNguyen I have already added the new reproducible example, it works fine but I need the same on the hole array, somehow I'm not able to do the same with the hole array (in the example I take the first two elements of the array as the input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this was the solution:

```
np.eye(array_classes + 1)[array]
```

Because I need the last index of my array to be the number of classes so I have to add +1 to `np.eye()`

Answer (score 0):

You use advanced indexing by using `array`. Values in `array` is out of bound for the array create by `np.eye`

```
print(np.eye(array_classes).shape)
# (6842, 6842)
```

I.e., the result of `np.eye` is a 2d-array having `6842 rows` and `6842 columns`. Its indices are from `0 - 6841`

Now, you do advanced indexing on it by using `array`

```
np.eye(array_classes)[array]
```

numpy use each value of `array` to index on `np.eye` output. Your `array` has several values greater than 6841 such as `6842, 6843`. So, when it hit the first `6842`, it errors out.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand what you're saying but is there any solution to this?

Comment: you either need to keep values in `array` less than `6842` or increase the shape of `np.eye` to accomodate the `array.max()`

Comment: Solved! I just needed to add +1 to the total number of classes when creating np.eye(), because if there are 6842 classes, get it reaches 6842 it errors out, I just need to add one to the classes:.